# CUDA: How to apply __restrict__ on array of pointers to arrays?

Tags: cuda, restrict-qualifier

This kernel using two `__restrict__` int arrays compiles fine:

```
__global__ void kerFoo( int* __restrict__ arr0, int* __restrict__ arr1, int num )
{
    for ( /* Iterate over array */ )
        arr1[i] = arr0[i];  // Copy one to other
}
```

However, the same two int arrays composed into a pointer array fails compilation:

```
__global__ void kerFoo( int* __restrict__ arr[2], int num )
{
    for ( /* Iterate over array */ )
        arr[1][i] = arr[0][i];  // Copy one to other
}
```

The error given by the compiler is:

```
error: invalid use of `restrict'
```

I have certain structures that are composed as an array of pointers to arrays. (For example, a struct passed to the kernel that has `int* arr[16]`.) How do I pass them to kernels and be able to apply `__restrict__` on them?

Comment: `__restrict__` really is useful for pointers but `int* arr[2]` actually is an array if two points. I think, it does not work for host code to...

Comment: Restrict is really get you some performance benefits??

Comment: That second use of `__restrict__` make absolutely no sense. The whole point of `__restrict__` is to tell the compiler that two or more pointer arguments will never overlap in memory. You don't have two pointer arguments in that case, so `__restrict__` is not applicable.

Comment: Why not `int * __restrict__ * __restrict__ arr`?  That may be excessive, though. You may only need `int * __restrict__ * arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in the comment in your code with some arbitrary iteration, we get the following program:

```
__global__ void kerFoo( int* __restrict__ arr[2], int num )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1024; i ++)
        arr[1][i] = arr[0][i];  // Copy one to other
}
```

and this [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/mYAvNx) with CUDA 10.1 (Godbolt.org).

Answer (score 2):

The CUDA C manual only refers to the C99 definition of `__restrict__`, no special CUDA-specific circumstances.

Since the indicated parameter is an array containing two pointers, this use of `__restrict__` looks perfectly valid to me, no reason for the compiler to complain IMHO. I would ask the compiler author to verify and possibly/probably correct the issue. I'd be interested in different opinions, though.

One remark to @talonmies:

> The whole point of **restrict** is to tell the compiler that two or more pointer arguments will never overlap in memory.

This is not strictly true. `restrict` tells the compiler that the pointer in question, for the duration of its lifetime, is the only pointer through which the pointed-to object can be accessed. Be aware that the object pointed to is only *assumed* to be an array of `int`. (In truth it's only one `int` in this case.) Since the compiler cannot know the size of the array, it is up to the programmer to guard the array's boundaries..